# Text with inset shadow three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to create text with inset shadow on my object in three.js, which looks like this:

[image: rings]

Something like ring with engraved text.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easier way to do that would be to use a [normal-map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) for the engraving, at least if the text doesn't have to be dynamic ([here's how you can export a normal-map from blender](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/bake-normal-maps.php)). And even if it needs to be dynamic it might be easier to create a normal-map dynamically in a canvas than to actually create a geometry for the engraving.

Another option would be to actually create a geometry that contains the engraving. For that you might want to look at the [ThreeCSG](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG)-library, that let's you use boolean operators on geometries: You create the 3D-text mesh, warp and align it to the curvature of the ring and finally subtract it from the ring-mesh. This should give you the ring with the engraving spared out.

In fact, I was curious how this would actually work out and implemented something very similar here: https://usefulthink.github.io/three-text-warp-csg/ ([source here](https://github.com/usefulthink/three-text-warp-csg/)).
In essence, This is using ThreeCSG to subtract a text-geometry from a cylinder-geometry like so:

```
const textBSP = new ThreeBSP(textGeometry);
const cylinderBSP = new ThreeBSP(cylinderGeometry);      
const resultGeometry = cylinderBSP.subtract(textBSP).toGeometry();

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(resultGeometry, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial());
```

Turns out that the tessellation created by threeCSG really slow (I had to move it into a worker so the page doesn't freeze for almost 10 seconds). It doesn't look too good right now, as there is still a problem with the computed normals that i haven't figured out yet.

The third option would be to use a combination of displacement and normal-maps.
This would be a lot easier and faster in processing, but you would need to add a whole lot of vertices in order to have vertices available where you want an displacement to happen. Here is a small piece of code by mrdoob that can help you with creating the normal-map based on the displacement: http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/height2normal/

Comment: The text needs to be created dynamically, so map isn't a great idea in this situation.

Comment: What's preventing you from dynamically generating the texture?